# Sem retorno quando aplicação vai para o servidor

Tags: php, data

Estou chamando as seguintes funções para pegar a data e o ano atuais:

```
$mes = date("m");
$ano = date("Y");
```

Isso funciona quando estou em `localhost`, porém, quando subo a aplicação para o servidor não recebo nenhuma informação desses métodos. Estou usando o PHP 5.3.

Alguma sugestão de como fazer essa informação aparecer?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Sim, adicione essas linhas no início do arquivo, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` e veja se aparece algum erro. Pode ser o caso do timezone não estar definido. Aproveite e veja alguns materias sobre php na [wiki](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) e não deixe de ver a [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Fora isso não tentei mais nada, porque em locallhost tudo aparece corretamente. Sou novo no PHP, então não tenho muita ideia do que está acontecendo.

Comment: É só esse código que da problema? não tem mais nada?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Vou verificar o timezone.

Comment: Aparece algum erro? coloque(edite) ele na pergunta

Comment: @James_Evans você tem apenas um arquivo simples em PHP com apenas essas duas chamadas ou tem mais coisas? As versões do PHP da sua máquina e do servidor são iguais? Ou pelo menos compatíveis? O apache do servidor está rodando OK?

Comment: Não aparece. Bem, setei o timezone e vou subir a aplicação para o servidor e ver se aparece algo, porque em localhost continua tudo ok.

Comment: localhost usa a mesma versão do php que o host de produção?

Comment: @rray, em produção o PHP é 5.3 e em desenvolvimento é o 5.5

Comment: O código que tem na pergunta é o mesmo código que está dando problema no hosto de produção ou tem mais coisa?

Comment: @rray, é o mesmo código.

Comment: wtf?, pode ser problema na instalação do php no host de produção, muito estranho isso

Comment: Pois é... vou esperar o pessoal do suporte pôr o sistema em produção para ver o que rola. Obrigado pela ajuda!